# Making the private function accessible to external files

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype

How to make a private function accessible to another file. I have below two files where I am trying to access msg() in File2.js. How can I achieve this without making any changes in File1.js

```
File1.js
    function test() {

    }
    test.prototype.first = function () {
        msg("abc");
    }
    function msg(name) {
        console.log("hello " + name);
    }
    module.exports = test;

File2.js
var test = require("./File1");
console.log(test.msg("xyz"))
```

I am getting error as

> TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: you can put the 'msg' function inside the 'test' function, or add it to the prototype of the 'test' function. If you don't want to modify File1,js, then try calling 'first' function instead of calling 'msg' function since that one is already in the prototype of the 'test' function, but be careful because the 'first' function doesn't accept parameter and has "abc" hardcoded.

Comment: When something is accessible in another file then it is not private

Answer (score 0):

I'm not JavaScript programmer but your msg function is outside test classs.

So you need either use prototype or put this function inside test() function to make it work.

change your msg() to

```
test.prototype.msg = function(name) {
    console.log("hello " + name);
}
```

Moreover, because it's already has console.log inside you can use it just like below

```
test.msg("xyz");
```

and it should be printed to console

Answer (score 0):

Probably many ways to deal with that situation, but here how I would do with some modification in your code:

I don't think this is strictly speaking a private method, the *test* function is some kind of Constructor and the *msg* function is not accessible until you export it.
I also change the *console.log* in the *msg* prototype to a *return* statement, because it will be undefined.

```
File1.js
    function test() {

    }
    test.prototype.first = function () {
        msg("abc");
    };
    test.prototype.msg = function(name) {
        return("hello " + name);
    };

    module.exports = test;


File2.js
    var Test = require("./File1");
    test = new Test();
    console.log(test.msg("xyz"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I "think" what your looking for is something similar to friend functions in C++. I would consider this a code smell as it breaks encapsulation. Regardless, Javascript doesn't support this concept AFAIK.

Additionally, you will get an error even if you called `test.first()` in File2.js. This is because you haven't actually created an object yet using the constructor function you are exporting in File1.js

Ultimately, there's not a way to do what you want without modifying the first file. The most straightforward way of doing this in your current implementation would be to add it to the prototype so every object instance of the module gets it. However, like others stated, your function is no longer considered private.

If it's meant to be a "static" utility function, you could extract it another file (i.e util.js) that exported it in an object literal.